# Ruby on Rails Devise Reset Password Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the letter_opener gem to test my Devise reset password functionality in the development environment.

One of the things I require when a new user signs up is for them to type in their e-mail twice. Here's the code in my `User` model:

```
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true
validates_confirmation_of :email
```

This works fine until I try testing the password reset functionality. On the page you input your new password twice and submit, it throws an error that `Email confirmation can't be blank.` Even if I stick the e-mail and e-mail confirmation fields in there to see what happens and type something in it, it still thinks the field is blank.

I could change my model code to look something like:

```
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true, unless: {action: :edit}
validates_confirmation_of :email, unless: {action: :edit}
```

But then it won't keep the e-mail confirmation validation if a user is just regularly editing his/her e-mail address in their account profile.

So, I would like to know if there is a way to either make it so that the reset password page doesn't think it needs the e-mail confirmation, or if there is a way to edit my `unless` statement in my model to apply the exception only when specifically editing on the password reset page. Thanks for any help, on Rails 4 with Devise 3.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true, if: :new_record?
```

**Edit**

If you want to validate this field only if email has changed, you could do this:

```
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true, if: :email_changed?
```

I think it would be valid to both cases:

- when user is a new record
- when user edits the email

Try this out!

Comment: But what if the user is editing their e-mail address? It would be nice to have them put a confirmation e-mail in there.

Comment: Oh! I never knew about :field_changed! Woo hoo! Thanks so much, that did work.